# Problema ao tentar fazer uma subtração constante no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estava querendo criar joguinho muito simples em que consiste em apertar em um botão, após isso o programa daria dois números aleatórios e a vida de cada personagem cairia conforme esse número, porém sempre que aperto o botão novamente a vida reseta e fica nesse loop infinito.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void batalha(View view){
        //Criando variaveis e colocando valor nelas
        //Vinculação dos objetos
        TextView paladino = findViewById(R.id.txthppaladino);
        TextView quimera = findViewById(R.id.txthpquimera);
        int hppaladino, hpquimera;
        hppaladino = 200;
        hpquimera = 200;
        int danopaladino = new Random().nextInt(50);
        int danoquimera = new Random().nextInt(50);
        hppaladino = hppaladino - danoquimera;
        hpquimera = hpquimera - danopaladino;
        //Criando um AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder dano = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        //Alterar titulo
        dano.setTitle("Dano");
        //Alterar mensagem
        dano.setMessage("Dano do Paladinho foi " +danopaladino+" e o Dano da Quimera foi " +danoquimera);
        //Alterar mensagem da caixa
        dano.setNeutralButton("Fechar", null);
        //Mostrando o Alert Dialog
        dano.show();
        paladino.setText("HP Paladino = " +hppaladino);
        quimera.setText("HP Quimera = " +hpquimera);
        if (hppaladino <=0 && hpquimera >=0){
            AlertDialog.Builder vitoria1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            //Alterar titulo
            dano.setTitle("Parabéns");
            //Alterar mensagem
            dano.setMessage("Vitória da Quimera =D");
            //Alterar mensagem da caixa
            dano.setNeutralButton("Fechar", null);
            //Mostrando o Alert Dialog
            dano.show();
        }
        if (hppaladino >= 0 && hpquimera <=0){
            AlertDialog.Builder vitoria1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            //Alterar titulo
            dano.setTitle("Parabéns");
            //Alterar mensagem
            dano.setMessage("Vitória do Paladino =D");
            //Alterar mensagem da caixa
            dano.setNeutralButton("Fechar", null);
            //Mostrando o Alert Dialog
            dano.show();
        }
        if (hppaladino <= 0 && hpquimera <= 0){
            AlertDialog.Builder vitoria1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            //Alterar titulo
            dano.setTitle("Triste");
            //Alterar mensagem
            dano.setMessage("Ocorreu um empate ;-;");
            //Alterar mensagem da caixa
            dano.setNeutralButton("Fechar", null);
            //Mostrando o Alert Dialog
            dano.show();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa inicializa os TextViews sempre na ação do botão, tanto eles como hppaladino e hpquimera dentro do onCreate. Do jeito que você está fazendo sempre que clica no botão os valores hppaladino e hpquimera sempre são 200.

Então ficaria algo assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declara as suas variáveis principais
    private TextView paladino, quimera;
    private int hppaladino, hpquimera;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Inicializando variáveis
        paladino = findViewById(R.id.txthppaladino);
        quimera = findViewById(R.id.txthpquimera);
        hppaladino = 200;
        hpquimera = 200;
    }

    public void batalha(View view) {
        int danopaladino = new Random().nextInt(50);
        // restante do seu código igual...
    }
}
```